# How can I extract ids of forms from specific urls using regEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

Pls help me... I'm not fimiliar to regular expressions. I need to extract screen version Ids from different urls:

1. localhost:8080/myapp/desktop/screen-0.0.1-beta/main
2. localhost:8080/myapp/desktop/screen-1.1/main
3. localhost:8080/myapp/desktop/admin-1/something

So that result would be 1) 0.0.1-beta 2) 1.1 3) 1 .
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So first step would be to [learn regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the following tutorial; learning regular expressions has a good ROI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex.

```
var strs = [
    'localhost:8080/myapp/desktop/screen-0.0.1-beta/main',
    'localhost:8080/myapp/desktop/screen-1.1/main',
    'localhost:8080/myapp/desktop/admin-1/something'];

for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    var vid = strs[i].match(/-(.+)-*\//)[1];
    alert(vid);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nZXjk/

Answer (score 0):

```
// capture the text following the 'desktop/text-'
var version = url.match(/desktop\/\w*-(.*)\//)[1];

alert(version);
```